# Text break when I didn't want when insert another <div> inside <div>

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm making my own website and when I insert div inside another div the line break. How do I fix this?

```css
    .subt {
    font-size: 21.75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    }
    .norm {
    font-size: 19.5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .god {
    font-style: italic;
    }
```

```html
    <pre>
    <div class="normal"><b>3</b> Ent Jous dit alors: « <div class="god">Que la loumin soiz!</div> » Ent la loumin fut</div></pre>
```

Comment: divs are block level elements.  Either use `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` or use a span or other inline element.

Comment: _“How do I fix this?”_ - well ideally you would go through some beginner’s tutorials on your own, so that we don’t have to explain these absolute basics here, which is not the job of this site to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You need set `display:inline-block;` or `display:inline;` for your .god class.

```
.god {
font-style: italic;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
.subt {
font-size: 21.75px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
}
.norm {
font-size: 19.5px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
.god {
font-style: italic;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<style> 


</style>
<pre>
<div class="normal"><b>3</b> Ent Jous dit alors: « <div class="god">Que la loumin soiz!</div> » Ent la loumin fut</div></pre>
```

Comment: Or inline-block, yeah! I suggested span, but could use anything really as long as it's inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default the `div` element has a styling `display: block`.

What you'd want to use instead is a `<span>` to keep the flow of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use span instead of div. Or set the div to `display:inline`

```
.normal > div {
  display:inline;
}
```

There's a typo in your style, you are using `.norm` instead of `.normal`